# Complex fourier transformation function

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, fourier-transform, complex-numbers

can the FT function can be a complex function ? and if yes what does it mean because in all cases i came across till now the FT function only had a real part

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/645148/2451

Comment: Hi peter mafai. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.